# Can rosyln code fixes be applied via a command line utility?

Tags: command-line-interface, roslyn

It is possible to [apply analyzers to code via a command line utility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35322126/64348). Is it possible to apply the corresponding code fix to the code in this utility?

What I would like to do is query a NuGet package containing analyzers, run all of them against a code base, and have them apply the corresponding code fix for each instance detected.

Comment: "Yes." As long as you're willing to write the tool. :-)

Comment: Has anyone written such a tool, or know of a tool that can do this? Asking for a friend. :) --Update, this looks promising: https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator/blob/master/docs/HowToFixAllDiagnostics.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyzers included in NuGet packages already should be running as a part of the compiler, so msbuild is sufficient. There's no tool I know of (yet) that automatically applies codefixes. You'd want to be careful with that: not all code fixes might be "safe" to apply, or you might have two code fixes that just change the code from one bad state to another!

Comment: So there is no dependency on any kind of context? Specifically context related to the IDE? I'm guessing no, and admit to not going that far yet.

Comment: Some codefixes may have VS IDE dependencies, but not all of them. Consider code fixes that run in VS Code on Linux. :-)

Comment: The tool is there: look at the test helpers that are provided with a Diagnostic + Code Fix solution template -- for the purpose of being able to test code fixes, these are applied internally. The relevant pieces are probably around here: https://github.com/Vannevelj/RoslynTester/blob/master/RoslynTester/RoslynTester/Helpers/CodeFixVerifier.cs#L109 (look for the corresponding location in your test helper files)

Comment: For an example of writing your own console app that applies analyzers you can look at these same tester files or look at the example here: https://github.com/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/blob/consoleapp/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics.Console/Program.cs